# Database model issue with multiple cascade paths and 'on delete set null'

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, cascade

Here's a simplified version of a database model I'm currently working with:

[image: Simple DB model of stores and customers (crow's foot DB notation)]

Quick explanation of the domain:

- Each store can have multiple customers. Each customer entity references a single application user account (i.e. many-to-many relationship between User and Store).
- Each store can have discount categories setup (a store may also have none setup).
- A customer can be added to a discount category to get a discount when making purchases at the store.

I currently have an 'ON DELETE CASCADE' on the FK between Customer and Store. That is, customers of a store are deleted when the store is deleted. I also have an 'ON DELETE CASCADE' on the FK between Discount Category and Store. That is, discount categories of the store are deleted when the store is deleted.

Consider now the case where a store owner wants to remove a discount category. I would like to setup an 'ON DELETE SET NULL' on the FK between Customer and Discount Category.

If I try to do this in SqlServer it complains with the usual 'multiple cascade paths' issue.

Question: Is there any elegant way to remodel this problem so that customers are removed from a discount category (i.e. set the FK to null) when that discount category is deleted, whilst still keeping my other cascade relationships? Assume that I can't move away from SqlServer.

Comment: Diamond-shaped cascades can be fairly simply emulated via triggers. Is there a specific reason you are trying avoid that?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Branko. I had a look into triggers. If I understand correctly, an AFTER trigger won't work because the FKs need to be closed BEFORE the delete happens. An INSTEAD OF trigger also won't work because I have a cascade delete defined between Store and Discount Category.

Comment: P.S. Novi Sad's lovely :). I liked it more than Belgrade!

Comment: Actually, you'll need INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger, but you'll need to implement such triggers all the way down. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17680539/533120). And thanks for liking my city :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement ON CASCADE DELETE via an INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger, which will work even when there are multiple cascading paths.

Here is a "template":

```
CREATE TRIGGER PARENT_TRIGGER ON PARENT_TABLE INSTEAD OF DELETE AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE FROM CHILD_TABLE
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM deleted
        WHERE CHILD_TABLE.PK = deleted.PK
    );

    -- You can DELETE from other child table here, etc...

END
GO
```

Please note that you won't be able to mix declarative cascade and trigger - you'll need to implement triggers all the way down.

Comment: Hvala Branko. Considering my initial question I think your answer is correct, however I ended up solving the problem in a different way because I did not want to implement triggers on the entire cascade branch. My solution involves batch-updating all the customers (closing their FKs) when a Discount Category is deleted (all in the one transaction for atomicity) from an application level. For my situation this is a better approach than a full branch of triggers. Ziveli :).